# How to swap two parameters of a variadic template at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm trying to swap two parameters of a variadic template at compile time :

```
 template<int...Numbers>struct sequence{};

template<size_t first,size_t second>
struct Swap_Pair
{
    const static size_t First = first;
    const static size_t Second = second;
};

template <int...Numbers,class swap_pair>
struct Swap_Data
{
    static std::array<int, sizeof...(Numbers)> data_;//How to swap Numbers base on the pair and store it in data_ ?
};
```

**The use case should be :**

```
sequence<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6> array;
auto result = Swap_Data < array, Swap_Pair<2, 5> > ::data_;
//result is now std::array which contains 1 2 6 4 5 3
```

I can't figure out what is the proper way of writing `Swap_Data` .

And how can I make a recursive swap for swapping variadic parameters and converting into std::array at compile time ?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/reboot/bind.hpp

Comment: Something like `int swapped_arr[] = { unswapped_arr[N == swap_pair::First ? swap_pair::Second : N == swap_pair::Second ? swap_pair::First : N]... };` where you have an array of the unswapped elements; you could also use some `integer_sequence` with a `get<N>(seq)` functions.

Comment: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df8eac60c18156bc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link I posted on the comment is my own implementation of a `std::bind()`-like metafunction for metafunctions.

What I did is to transform the `bind` call parameters from its value (A value or a placeholder) to a value, or the value represented by that placeholder.

In your case you could try a similar approach: Map the sequence from placeholders (The values passed to swap) to the corresponding values of the sequence. Something like:

```
template<std::size_t I>
struct placeholder{};

using _1 = placeholder<0>;
... //More placeholder aliases

template<typename SEQ , typename... PLACEHOLDERS>
struct swap;

template<std::size_t... Is , std::size_t... Ps>
struct swap<sequence<Is...>,placeholder<Ps>...>
{
    template<typename PLACEhOLDER>
    struct transformation;

    template<std::size_t I>
    struct transformation<placeholder<I>>
    {
        static constexpr const std::size_t result = get<sequence<Is...>,I>::value;
    };

    using result = map<transformation,sequence<Is...>>;
};
```

Where `map` is a metafunction similar to `std::transform()` (Very easy to write), and `get` a metafunction which retrieves the Ith element of a sequence (Easy too).

This could be used on this way:

```
 using swapped = typename swap<sequence<1,2,3>,_3,_2,_1>::result; //swapped is sequence<3,2,1>
```